# Asp.net Validator does not generate code if created during postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a control in a dock that has a couple validators in it (for required fields).  If the dock is expanded on page load, The validators will work (since it seems there are 5 references to the validators, 3 of which are auto generated javascript functions).  But if the dock is closed, the control (as well as the validators) are not generated.  On expanding the control, I create the control in an ajax request, but then the validators stop working.  When I check the source code, the javascript is not being generated for the validators.  Anyone know what to do about this?  The control is wrapped in an update panel, so it shouldn't be an issue about updating the DOM, but rather about its not inserting the javascript automatically.  Thanks!

```
<RadAjaxPanel id="RadAjaxPanel" runat="server>

<ValidationSummary id="ValidationSummary" validationgroup="ValidationGroup" CSSclass="error" runat="server"/>
<Validator id="Validator" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ValidationGroup"/>
<CustomControl id=CustomControl runat="server"/>

</RadAjaxPanel>
```

Comment: Please post your code and markup.

Comment: Can you put your validators on the page rather than in your control?

Comment: No, I would rather keep the validators in the control.  If thats impossible (because you can't inject javascript into the parent page), then that's okay.

Comment: I am not familiar with the dock, however, why not keep the dock open, allow it to generate everything you need, then use $(document).ready() and closed the dock.